# How to update many rows with random values

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, random, sql-update

I would like to perform update query to table and set 2 columns to random values. Here is an example:

`Update Network_Info_Detail set ART = (rand()*4000)+2, NRT = (rand()*1000)+2`

It's obvious that all rows will be updated with the same value randomly generated so I needed to create a cycle to generate a random value for each row.

`DECLARE @size integer
SET @size = (SELECT Count(*) from Network_Info_Detail)
While @size > 1 
BEGIN
Update top (@size) Network_Info_Detail set ART = (rand()*4000)+2, NRT = (rand()*1000)+2
SET @size = @size - 1
END`

This script updates rows with different numbers, but it's very slow. Is there a way to improve the execution time?

Comment: Added sql-server tag because the syntax (and problem) are clearly SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a SQL Server trick to generate a random number:  `rand(checksum(newid()))`.

```
Update Network_Info_Detail
    set ART = (rand(checksum(newid()))*4000)+2,
        NRT = (rand(checksum(newid()))*1000)+2;
```